# Default page code behind not working when published on hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I decided not to redirect a first visitor from default to my "Not Logged In" page and just turn default in the "Not Logged In" page.  When i did this, none of the code is working in the codebehind except for the page load. I have a menu that works perfectly fine, but any link button, or login code in the master page is not working.  Maybe it has to do with the url rewriting the hosting provider does?  My page doesn't have default.aspx in the url it just shows www.mywebsite.com

Here is my page load on default.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            AbuseReport abuse = new AbuseReport();
            abuse.Message = "page load clicked";
            abuse.ReportingPersonID = 1;
            abuse.AbuserPersonID = 1;
            abuse.CreateAbuseReport();

            SiteViews();

            bool stayOnSite = (Session["StayOnMainSite"] != null && !Parser.GetBoolean(Session["StayOnMainSite"]));

            string strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();

            if (strUserAgent != null)
            {
                if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true || strUserAgent.Contains("iphone") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("blackberry") || strUserAgent.Contains("mobile") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("windows ce") || strUserAgent.Contains("opera mini") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("palm") || strUserAgent.Contains("android") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("ipad") || strUserAgent.Contains("moto") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("htc") || strUserAgent.Contains("sony") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("panasonic") || strUserAgent.Contains("midp") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("cldc") || strUserAgent.Contains("avant") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("windows ce") || strUserAgent.Contains("nokia") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("pda") || strUserAgent.Contains("hand") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("mobi") || strUserAgent.Contains("240x320") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("voda"))
                {
                    if (!stayOnSite)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Mobile/Default.aspx");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Session[ApplicationClass.UserSessions.AppUser] != null)
            {
                ApplicationClass appClass = ((ApplicationClass)Session[ApplicationClass.UserSessions.AppUser]);

                if (appClass.User.IsPolitician)
                {
                    UrlParameterPasser urlPasser = new UrlParameterPasser("~/PoliticianView/PoliticianWall.aspx");
                    urlPasser["PoliticianID"] = Parser.GetString(appClass.User.Politician.PoliticianID);
                    urlPasser.PassParameters();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/User/UserMain.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my login click (register is the same, and the abuse is just for logging purpose right now)

```
protected void lbtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbuseReport abuse = new AbuseReport();
        abuse.Message = "Login clicked";
        abuse.ReportingPersonID = 1;
        abuse.AbuserPersonID = 1;
        abuse.CreateAbuseReport();

        Response.Redirect("~/Login/Login.aspx");

        AbuseReport abuse2 = new AbuseReport();
        abuse2.Message = "Login after click";
        abuse2.ReportingPersonID = 1;
        abuse2.AbuserPersonID = 1;
        abuse2.CreateAbuseReport();
    }
```

here is defualt.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Politic Profiles Main" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TwoColumn.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="PoliticProfiles._Default" %>
```

```
<table cellpadding="10px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/flags.jpg" AlternateText="American Flags" 
                runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <h1>Welcome to Politic Profiles</h1>

            <h2>Political information tailored to you.</h2>

            <br />

            <h3>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnRegister" runat="server" Text="Register" 
                onclick="lbtnRegister_Click" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text=" or " runat="server" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" 
                onclick="lbtnLogin_Click"/>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=" to get the most out of your experience." />
            </h3>

            <ul class="landing">
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Ask your politicians questions." />
                    <br /><br />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Keep up to date with what your politicians are doing." />
                    <br /><br />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Allow your politicians to learn from you." />
                    <br /><br />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Be involved in polls that help inform you politicians what track you want them on." />
                    <br /><br />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<uc:Polls id="ucPolls" runat="server" />

<br /><br /> 

<uc:Donate id="ucDonate" runat="server" />
```

Comment: is your page public facing right now?  can you send me a url so I can check out a more verbose error?

Comment: or maybe post your code behind and aspx page for the "not logged in" page

Comment: www.politicprofiles.com  If you click home it will actually take you to the same page but it works then.  I have a feeling it is something with the url rewrite.

Comment: im not getting any errors when I click around?  Is there a use case I should follow in order to cause an error?

Comment: just go to the www.politicprofiles.com url, then click on login or register next to the flags.  It just refreshes the page and doesn't go to the links.  I have it logging in that method and it doesn't get hit.  But if you go to www.politicprofiles.com/default.aspx it works just fine.

Comment: so when you "turned" your default page into the not logged in page did you copy and paste code from "not logged in" into "default", or did you try to change the class name and file name of "not logged in" to default.  Either way it would be extremely helpful to see some code.

Comment: i copied the code.  i didn't want to mess up any renaming when i did it.  I'm not sure what code you would like to see?

Comment: I'll be off for about 20 minutes, it would be helpful to see default.aspx and default.aspx.cs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6633/discussion-between-mike-and-andy-xufuris)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be because i had enableCrossAppRedirects="true"